# Change the color of the buttons in a UINavigationController view and buttons (e.g. Back)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uinavigationcontroller

It's possible to change color of UINavigationController view and buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the color of the nav bar via:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar]; 
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The buttons will then pick up that color as well.